# Ubuntu 18.04 external monitor not detected since recent update

Tags: updates, multiple-monitors, display

I am on Dell xps 13 9360 with Ubuntu 18.04.2. My laptop could not detect external monitor since some automatic updates last week. I am connecting the monitor through a USB-C to VGA and it worked well for over half a year. I did not install any driver for that. Occasionally during this week, the monitor was detected twice, but when I unplugged, it had no luck to show up. Looks like this is pretty random.

I thought of the kernel update which may lead to the problem. The recent update brings it to Linux 4.15.0-45-generic. I tried to boot to 4.15.0-43-generic or 4.15.0-44-generic but found no help.

Running command xrandr it only shows the built-in monitor.

I do not know whether the problem comes with the updates or not. Does anyone meet such a issue or have suggestions on this? Thanks!

Comment: i having the same problem here now.

Comment: I solved it by installing DisplayLink 4.4. Still on Linux 4.15.0-45-generic.